# Excel Index and Match in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I got an excel table with this format

```
    DATE       AREA        BEAU EFFORT  SEASON  VESSEL         P/S
0   2016-04-01  SE LANTAU   1   16.24   SPRING  STANDARD31516   P
1   2016-04-01  SE LANTAU   2   10.23   SPRING  STANDARD31516   P
2   2016-04-01  SE LANTAU   1   4.82    SPRING  STANDARD31516   S
3   2016-04-01  SE LANTAU   2   2.98    SPRING  STANDARD31516   S
4   2016-04-01     LAMMA    1   2.92    SPRING  STANDARD31516   P
```

And I got another excel table with this format

```
    DATE      STG # TIME    HRD SZ  AREA  BEAU PSD EFFORT TYPE NORTHING EASTING SEASON BOATASSOC.P/S
0   2016-04-06  1   1025    12  W LANTAU    2   58  ON  HKCRP   813713  802792  SPRING  NONE    S
1   2016-04-06  2   1113    3   W LANTAU    4   27  ON  HKCRP   806173  802043  SPRING  NONE    S
2   2016-04-06  3   1345    2   SW LANTAU   2   ND  OFF HKCRP   805606  803300  SPRING  NONE    NaN
3   2016-04-14  1   1613    4   W LANTAU    2   74  ON  HKCRP   808800  800864  SPRING  NONE    S
4   2016-04-20  1   1339    4   W LANTAU    3   ND  OFF HKCRP   805930  801929  SPRING  NONE    NaN
```

I would like to add numbers in the EFFORT columns of the first table to table 2 if DATE, AREA, BEAU and P/S match between two table.

Should i join, merge or map the two tables?

Comment: There is main problem you want merge with duplicated columns? `06/04/2016,W LANTAU,S ` is duplicate and in second df2 too.

Comment: I would like to do an operation like the index and match function in excel. but with multiple criteria (col 1,2 and the last col)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both merge and join

First groupby col1,col2 and last column

```
# My assumption is col1 + col2 + col_last when used as index cannot be duplicated
temp = df_2.groupby(['col1','col2','col_last']).first()
# df is the dataframe in which you want the extra column
df = df.merge(temp,left_on=['col1','col2','col_last'],right_index=True,how='left')
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but it does not work. Can you see my modified question. Hope that provide more information.

Comment: Just use this line df3= df2.merge(df1[['DATE', 'AREA', 'BEAU','P/S','EFFORT']],on=['DATE', 'AREA', 'BEAU','P/S'],how='left')

Comment: It works now. The reason it didn't work is I got some space in the content and inconsistent between two dataframe. After I remove the spaces, it works.

Comment: df4 = pd.merge(sighting, effort[['DATE', 'AREA', 'BEAU','P/S','EFFORT']], on = ['DATE', 'AREA', 'BEAU','P/S'], how = 'left')

This is equivalent to your code???